# How to test Azure functions with environment variables locally in Java?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I'm developing an azure function in java with VS Code.
From the documentation I got the impression I could add a variable in local.settings.json and access this with System.getenv("someVariable") when running the function locally. But this always fails for me and System.getenv() returns null.

Would really appriciate any hints here.

Comment: A citation to the documentation you mentioned might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Might need to see some code, but you could always do something like the following. Basically, do not call `System.getenv(...)` directly, hide this behind a method call, for example...

```
public class Func {
    ...

    protected String getSetting(String setting) {
        return System.getenv(setting);
    }

    ...

    public ? theFunction(...args...) {
        String widgets = getSetting("widgets");

        ...
    }
}
```

To unit test this, you can override `getSetting`, for example...

```
public class FuncTest {
    private Func classUnderTest;
    private Map<String, String> overriddenSettings = new HashMap<>();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        classUnderTest = new Func() {
            @Override
            protected String getSetting(String setting) {
                return overriddenSettings.get(setting);
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDoSomethingWhenThereAre10Widgets() {
        overriddenSettings.put("widgets", "10");

        classUnderTest.theFunction(...);

        ...
    }
}
```

You could also use PowerMock to mock out the System.getenv method, but PowerMock can make things a mess sometimes in mhy opinion...

Hope this helps.